# Log format to get request header in gunicorn access log

Tags: gunicorn

I am trying this log format when running gunicorn:

```
--access-logformat "[dev.api] %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s .%(r)s. %(s)s %(b)s .%(f)s. .%(a)s. conn=\"%{Connection}i\""
```

This looks ok according to the documentation @ http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html

But, I get the following error:

```
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/glogging.py", line 274,   in access
   self.access_log.info(self.cfg.access_log_format % safe_atoms)
 TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The problem is related to how I am requesting the Connection request header.

Does anyone have an example of logging a request header in the gunicorn format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I gather, it should be:

```
--access-logformat "[dev.api] %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s .%(r)s. %(s)s %(b)s .%(f)s. .%(a)s. conn=\"%({Connection}i)s\""
```

that is `%({Connection}i)s` instead of `%{Connection}i`, the error suggests there's an unknown substitution in your string, and that last one is the only thing not to follow the pattern, which is `%(variable-name)s`, `s` meaning string substitution.

Also, if you're looking for the request-header, it should probably be: `%({Header}i)s`, not sure if that'll give you the full header, or if you can select the `Connection` header explicitly through this.

Full disclosure though, I have no experience with gunicorn, I'm just reading the docs.